# Is there a way to use a char array/variable in #include

Tags: c

I want to use a variable as input for the #include statement, but i have to use the quotation marks which converts my variable to a simple string.

Is there a way to prevent this?

The code looks like this

```
void toObjectArray(char file_name[]){
  struct telefonbuchEintrag tListe[]=
  {
    #include file_name
  };
}
```

And i have to use quotation marks, is there a way to add them without changing my variable to a string?

Comment: Can't do it at runtime? Create a program (or script) that outputs C source code, then include the resulting output (`tempexec >tempfile.c` on the shell, and `#include "tempfile.c"` in your source with appropriate comments).

Comment: Includes are done at compile time. Variables have values at runtime. So this isn't possible.

Comment: You may need to look up x-macros.  But you can't use a function parameter value at run time to control what happens at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do won’t work - `#include` directives are not processed at runtime, but during the pre-processing phase of compilation.  IOW, you can’t execute an `#include` directive in a running program.

The question is *why* you want to do this - what problem are you trying to solve?  If you honestly have a situation where you to choose between multiple headers based on some condition, then you’ll have to write a program to *generate* that code and then compile the generated code.

Answer (score -1):

All the preprocessor directives including `#include` are processed before the actual `C` program compilation. C preprocessor does not know anything about the C language, and you cant use anything related to C in the preprocessing directives.

Comment: It is more accurate to say that preprocessing occurs early in compilation and is before the main part of compilation. It is not correct that the preprocessor “does not know anything about the C language.” Before preprocessing, there is some character processing specified by the C standard and then decomposition into grammatical tokens. As an example, attempting preprocessing on a text file will fail in various ways, such as if the text contains a quotation that begins with a quote mark on one line and ends with it on another…

Comment: … The decomposition into tokens includes parsing tokens such as string literals, character constants, and numeric constants that must have specific forms. The preprocessor also evaluates constant expressions, in `#if` and `#elif` directives. So telling students it does not know anything about C sets them up with a faulty model that causes misunderstandings later.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OP is a very beginner. Do you think that he can understand anything from your comment?

Comment: @EricPostpischil for him as for now: the rule of thumb - "do not use anything C related in the preprocessor directives".

Comment: Yes. As I have explained before, you do not have to teach a student all of the rules immediately. I am relating these rules to demonstrate to you that your statement is false and gives students the wrong idea, not to say you should teach them immediately. But what you should do is make a statement such as that preprocessing does not use run-time data rather than a false statement that it does not know anything about the C language. You can teach a student something about a behavior and leave it open for expansion later without either teaching the full idea or making false statements.

Comment: `#if sizeof(int) == 4` not only runtime. What I wrote is 100% correct for the OPs level. It is imprecise but will save him a lot of frustration. Later he will start to understand more.

Comment: “`#if sizeof(int) == 4` not only runtime” is not a sentence and I do not know what you are trying to say with it. My complaint with your statement in the answer is not that it is imprecise but that it is false. Knowingly teaching students false things is unethical.